# iPhone plist key-to-struct of values

Tags: iphone, plist

I am new to plists. They seem very powerful for static data but I'm not sure how to accomplish the following.

I have a table of data (a spreadsheet currently) where the first column is a unique id (perfect for the key) and I want that key to map to the a structure w/ the rest of the column's data.

I'm looking at my plist in XCode and I'm not quite sure how to set that up. It seems like it wants me to have the key result in only one value.

Also, is there an easy way to get all my spreadsheet data into the plist file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value associated with the key should be an array (or dictionary), which can then contain multiple values.

Comment: Something like this? http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/7808/plist.png

Is there an easy way to get my large spreadsheet (w/ this structure) into the plist?